# How can I make this image float right with absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="outside">
<img src="http://cox-applicators.com/images/brochures/vertical-ad-07-
singles.jpg" class="imgs">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .outside {
      position:absolute;
 }
 .imgs {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 30px;
 }
 .container {
     width: 960px;
 }
```

I have to use absolute because of another div that contains content.

**Question:**  How can I make the image float right with using margin-left while still having absolute on the containing div?

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/erjQH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add this line of css to ur code.

```
.outside {
      position:absolute;
      right:0; /* Add this to ur Code */
  }
```

With this u dont need to apply float to image and it will be aligned left

or

u can do this add this line to ur code and your image will be aligned right without float.

```
.imgs{          
          position:relative;
          right:0px;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by adding `right:30px;` in your `.outside` class without the need of `.imgs` class

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/U2WUK/